# Python: Opening a file without creating a lock

Tags: python, backup, file-locking, filestreams

I'm trying to create a script in Python to back up some files. But, these files could be renamed or deleted at any time. I don't want my script to prevent that by locking the file; the file should be able to still be deleted at any time during the backup.

How can I do this in Python? And, what happens? Do my objects just become null if the stream cannot be read?

Thank you! I'm somewhat new to Python.

Comment: The behaviour depends on the operating system. Which OS(es) do you need to support?

Comment: I do not think that you can do much about it. If the files get deleted while you are reading it you'll probably receive some `IOError` or `OSError`(in python there is no such thing as `null`. Even if the file is deleted the file object python is managing is not deleted and when doing the next system (or C)call it will fail thus raising an exception).

Comment: Normal `open()` on Python does not create locks. Further, advisory file system locking does not prevent deletion or renaming of a file, only reading and writing (and even that depends on the application using `flock()` correctly).

Comment: @FrancisAvila that's the situation on Unix, yes. On Windows, open files are "locked" so they can't be deleted (IIRC, there is a sharing mode for `CreateFile` to allow deletion, but it has some obscure problems...)

Comment: @Bakuriu: Reading from a deleted file in Linux works fine if you opened it before it was deleted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's why I said "probably". What I wanted to point out is that when the file is deleted python's file object still exists. Its behaviour will depend on the OS, but it wont simply become null and crash the whole interpreter.

Comment: I think I need something aside from VSS. @AntonKovalenko Others talk about the sharing flag when opening a file in Windows. Can we do this in Python? In .NET there's a FileShare.Delete flag, and here's the CreateFile link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Hmm.. I'm getting closer now, looks like I can use win32file.CreateFile to use the Windows specific dwSharingMode flag: http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/win32file__CreateFile_meth.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned by @kindall, this is a Windows-specific issue. Unix OSes allow deleting.

To do this in Windows, I needed to use [`win32file.CreateFile()`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32file__CreateFile_meth.html) to use the Windows-specific `dwSharingMode` flag (in Python's [`pywin32`](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/), it's just called `shareMode`).

Rough Example:

```py
import msvcrt
import os
import win32file

py_handle = win32file.CreateFile(
    'filename.txt',
    win32file.GENERIC_READ,
    win32file.FILE_SHARE_DELETE
        | win32file.FILE_SHARE_READ
        | win32file.FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
    None,
    win32file.OPEN_EXISTING,
    win32file.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    None
)
try:
    with os.fdopen(
        msvcrt.open_osfhandle(py_handle.handle, os.O_RDONLY)
    ) as file_descriptor:
        ... # read from `file_descriptor`
finally:
    py_handle.Close()
```

**Note:** if you need to keep the *win32-file* open beyond the lifetime of the *file-handle object* returned, you should invoke [`PyHandle.detach()`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/PyHANDLE__Detach_meth.html) on that handle.

Comment: Then you can use `os.fdopen(msvcrt.open_osfhandle(file_handle, os.O_RDONLY))` to transform that handle into a standard file object. Also, `os.fdopen()` can be used with `with` too, just as `open()`.

Answer (score 5):

On UNIX-like OSs, including Linux, this isn't an issue. Well, some other program could write to the file at the same time you're reading it, which could cause problems (the file you are copying could end up corrupted) but this is solvable with a verification pass.

On Windows, use Volume Snapshot Service (aka Volume Shadow Copy). VSS creates a snapshot of the volume at a moment in time, and you can open files on the snapshot without locking the files on the original volume. A quick Google found a Python module for doing copies using VSS here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyvss/

Comment: Accepted as answer, but I think I need something aside from VSS.