# Python crashes when using a static class

Tags: python, logging, file-io, locked-files

I'm making my first steps in Python and have come to a point where I need a logging module. The reasons I didn't opt for a rotating file handler are:

1. I wanted a new folder to be created each time the code is run, hosting the new log files.
2. Using conventional filenames (`myName_X.log`, and not the default `myName.log.X`).
3. Limit log files by number of lines, and not file size (as done by the rotating file handler).

I've written such a module, using Python's built in logging module, but i have two problems:

1. The new folder and file are created, and the logging data is printed into the file. However, when `main()` is run for the second time (see code below), the newly created file is locked, and cannot be deleted from the file explorer unless I close the IDE or release the lock through Process Explorer.
2. The IPython interpreter freezes the second time I run `main()`. If I try the `pdb` module, it freezes as well.

I'm using WinPython 3.3.5 (with Spyder 2.3.0beta). I spent hours trying to find a solution to this problem. I don't know if it is a problem in my code or rather a bug with Spyder.

General coding remarks are always welcome.

**main_example.py**:

```
import myLogging


def main():

    try:
        myLoggerInstance = myLogging.MyLogger()


        # Do stuff...


        # logging example
        for i in range(0, 3):
            msg = 'Jose Halapeno on a stick {0}'.format(i)
            myLoggerInstance.WriteLog('DEBUG', msg)
        print('end of prints...')


    finally:
        myLoggerInstance._closeFileHandler()
        print('closed file handle...')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**myLogging.py**:

```
import logging
import time
import os


class MyLogger:
    _linesCounter = 0
    _nNumOfLinesPerFile = 100000
    _fileCounter = 0
    _dirnameBase = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    _dirname = ''
    _filenameBase = 'logfile_{0}.log'
    _logger = logging.getLogger('innerGnnLogger')
    _severityDict = {'CRITICAL' : logging.CRITICAL, 'ERROR': logging.ERROR, 'WARNING':         
    logging.WARNING, 'INFO': logging.INFO, 'DEBUG': logging.DEBUG}


    @staticmethod
    def __init__():
        # remove file handle
        MyLogger._closeFileHandler()

        # create folder for session
        MyLogger._dirname = MyLogger._dirnameBase + time.strftime("\\logs_%Y_%m_%d-    
        %H_%M_%S\\")
        MyLogger._dirname = MyLogger._dirname.replace('\\\\', '/')
        if not os.path.exists(MyLogger._dirname):
            os.makedirs(MyLogger._dirname)

        # set logger
        MyLogger._logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


        # create console handler and set level to debug
        MyLogger._hConsole = logging.StreamHandler()
        MyLogger._hFile = logging.FileHandler(MyLogger._dirname + \
            MyLogger._filenameBase.format(MyLogger._fileCounter))
        MyLogger._hConsole.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
        MyLogger._hFile.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        # create formatter
        MyLogger._formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(filename)s, %(funcName)s, %(lineno)s, %(levelname)s: %(message)s')

        # add formatter to handlers
        MyLogger._hConsole.setFormatter(MyLogger._formatter)
        MyLogger._hFile.setFormatter(MyLogger._formatter)

        # add handlers to logger
        MyLogger._logger.addHandler(MyLogger._hConsole)
        MyLogger._logger.addHandler(MyLogger._hFile)


    @staticmethod
    def _StartNewFileHandler():

        MyLogger._closeFileHandler()

        # create new file handler
        ++MyLogger._fileCounter
        MyLogger._hFile = logging.FileHandler(MyLogger._dirname + \
            MyLogger._filenameBase.format(MyLogger._fileCounter))
        MyLogger._hFile.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        MyLogger._hFile.setFormatter(MyLogger._formatter)
        MyLogger._logger.addHandler(MyLogger._hFile)


    @staticmethod
    def WriteLog(severity, message):
        if (len(MyLogger._logger.handlers) < 2):
            MyLogger._StartNewFileHandler()
        MyLogger._linesCounter += 1
        MyLogger._logger.log(MyLogger._severityDict[severity], message)
        if (MyLogger._linesCounter >= MyLogger._nNumOfLinesPerFile):
            MyLogger._logger.info('Last line in file')
            MyLogger._StartNewFileHandler()
            MyLogger._linesCounter = 0


    @staticmethod
    def _closeFileHandler():
        if (len(MyLogger._logger.handlers) > 1):
            MyLogger._logger.info('Last line in file')
            MyLogger._logger.handlers[1].stream.close()
            MyLogger._logger.removeHandler(MyLogger._logger.handlers[1])
```

Comment: I think this post will answer your problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388608/python-opening-a-file-without-creating-a-lock

Comment: This looks like a workaround for deleting files. I believe it would still prevent my code from being run multiple times. I checked Python's logging directly, and it works fine, so the file handling part seems to work as expected. I suspect a reference problem (maybe because of the 'import' or the static class 'MyLogger').

Comment: @GL246 How are you running it, exactly? This is working fine on my machine.

Comment: @PatrickCollins, I'm running it with the gui commands "run" and "debug" from the Spyder menu. Have you tried running `main` several times in a row? Can you delete the newly created folders? What OS are you using? (I'm using Windows 7 64bit)

Comment: @GL246 I'm on Linux, I was running it inside an IPython shell. I didn't see any directories actually created though -- I suspect that's some cross-OS issue and I'm not sure I can provide any help for that reason.

Comment: Well, I found the problem. The handlers list has been growing each time `main` was run, because I deleted the second element of the handler's list:

MyLogger._logger.handlers[1].stream.close(). 

Mutating a list using explicit indexing was a bad idea, and instead the hFile handle itself should be deleted.